# Not able to insert data into remote mySQL Database using PHP

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to insert data into remote MySQL database using WP7 app but values does not get inserted, PHP file works perfect as my queries are getting inserted into DB using JAVA(Android). As I am new to C# I am facing this challenge.

The code goes like this:-

```
public MainPage()     
{
    InitializeComponent();         
    textBox1.Text = "http://www.abc.com/xyz/user_master.php?Email=abc@xyz.com&Username=abc&Password=xyzz&Phone=98989";
    client = new WebClient(); 
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
}
```

> ```
>     void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
>     { 
>         if (e.Error == null) 
>         { 
>             textBlock2.Text = e.Result; 
>         } 
>     }
>
>     private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     {
>
>         client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(textBox1.Text));
>     }
> ```

Please correct me.

Comment: When you set a breakpoint in `client_DownloadStringCompleted`, what do you see?

Comment: I get a success msg, if i check my DB table there is a row created it is blank...

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the url is correct? WebClient executes an HTTP-GET so the code you use is similar to using a web browser to navigate to this url. If the URL is ok, the only thing that remains is to debug the php page. You state that the php page is fine but from this code I doubt it.

Comment: I am getting success msg, rows are getting created so i don't think there should any problem with url.

Comment: **C# != PHP** You tagged this as php and ask a C# question

Comment: could you plz post the important parts of the php file and also the string in e.Result

Comment: <?php

$email = $_POST["Email"];

$username = $_POST["Username"];

$password = $_POST["Password"];

$phone = $_POST["Phone"];

$con= mysql_connect("MyDatabaseURL.com","UserName","Password");
 if (!$con)
   {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

 mysql_select_db("DB_Name",$con);

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO Sign_Up_Master (Email, UserName, Password, Phone)VALUES ('".$email."', '".$username."','".$password."','".$phone."')");

mysql_close($con);

echo 'Data Inserted';

?>

Comment: Guy problem solved... had done very basic mistake i.e. instead of GET used Post method. Thanks everyone for ur valuable comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using "DownloadStringAsync" which sends a GET and so you POST variable is not filled in PHP, you have to use "UploadStringAsync".

For now I can not tell you how the body has to look like... Until now I have used JSON all the time. Would be nice if you could post it here to let me know when you got it ;)

**update**

Ah, to slow =(
Could you please still post how your message body looks like!

Comment: That was the problem bro... i changed POST to GET which I forgot to check & problem solved...

Comment: And how does your body look like? Or how do you post the data?